# How do you make images on a website center on bigger screens

Tags: html, css

I am creating a project as one of my assignments. I am using dreamweaver on my laptop at home to make the site.
My images are centralized on my laptop but when i view my site on a bigger screen the images are closer to the left of the screen.

I have included the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Use `@media` queries to change the layout for different device widths.

Comment: Please, provide your css and html code.

Comment: Share your code, there are many situation that may lead to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code as this

```
<div style="background:url(/path/to/image.png) center top; width:100%; overflow:hidden">
```